# How can replace the rootViewController while using TTNavigator

Tags: iphone, three20

In my application i display a ViewController for Login. Once the user has logged in successfully I want to remove it completely from the NavigationController history and load the user account view controller.

Can this be done using TTNavigator module of Three20 library

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is easy.

First, init your main rootView (e.g. the tabBar). Then on top of that the login

```
[navigator openURLAction:[TTURLAction actionWithURLPath:@"pr://tabBar"]];
// now show the login page!
[navigator openURLAction:[TTURLAction actionWithURLPath:@"pr://accounts"]];

[navigator.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

now if you finished logging in, just remove the view from the stack.